# Design with IC ADP5091 for energy harvesting in Proteus

Tags: integrated-circuit, simulation, output, proteus

I want to design this IC ADP5091 using Proteus. But I'm still a newbie and not much understand about this software and this IC. Can anyone help me? Is it right I'm doing this simulation circuit?

Because I try to simulate and put DC voltmeter in pin reg_out but I get error code said that my simulation has an error and no model specified for this IC ADP5091. Can someone help me cause I don't know what to do?

[image]

Comment: I assume you want to design a circuit using that IC, not design the IC itself.

Comment: yes sir. i want to design using that ic.